# Error while inflating class android.support.v7.widget.toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar

Following a guide to make a small chat app.
But whenever I run the app and try to open the chat activity I get this Toolbar error

> Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.toolbar

Already tried solutions from another treads but this error still occurs. 
What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

**LogCat**

```
EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.leti.isaevruslan.diplomchat, PID: 31648
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.leti.isaevruslan.diplomchat/com.leti.isaevruslan.diplomchat.ui.activities.ChatActivity}: 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.toolbar
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.toolbar
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.toolbar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.toolbar" on path: 
DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.leti.isaevruslan.diplomchat-2/base.apk", 
zip file "/data/app/com.leti.isaevruslan.diplomchat-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", 
zip file "/data/app/com.leti.isaevruslan.diplomchat-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", 
zip file "/data/app/com.leti.isaevruslan.diplomchat-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", 
zip file "/data/app/com.leti.isaevruslan.diplomchat-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", 
zip file "/data/app/com.leti.isaevruslan.diplomchat-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", 
zip file "/data/app/com.leti.isaevruslan.diplomchat-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", 
zip file "/data/app/com.leti.isaevruslan.diplomchat-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", 
zip file "/data/app/com.leti.isaevruslan.diplomchat-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", 
zip file "/data/app/com.leti.isaevruslan.diplomchat-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", 
zip file "/data/app/com.leti.isaevruslan.diplomchat-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", 
zip file "/data/app/com.leti.isaevruslan.diplomchat-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],
nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.leti.isaevruslan.diplomchat-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:609)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
at com.leti.isaevruslan.diplomchat.ui.activities.ChatActivity.onCreate(ChatActivity.java:37)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
05-04 21:53:22.034 31648-31648/com.leti.isaevruslan.diplomchat 
E/AndroidRuntime:
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

**Dependencies**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
```

**Activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.leti.isaevruslan.diplomchat.ui.activities.LoginActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout_content_chat"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="@string/app_name"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: It's `Toolbar`, with an uppercase `T`  – `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`.

Answer (score 1):

It's Toolbar: android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

**Notice the T is capital**

Answer (score 1):

Use `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` instead of `android.support.v7.widget.toolbar`.

**Try this:**

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:title="@string/app_name"/>
```